# Fastest means of data transfer across wifi in python

Tags: python, performance, networking, wifi

I'm building an application that will need to communicate data across a wifi network. Since the data will be from sensors mounted on a moving platform, I need to minimize transport and encoding times. The max latency I'd be willing to tolerate is ~20ms, and I need at at least 60Hz. The amount of data is relatively small, so bandwidth shouldn't be an issue.

What I'm looking for is a way to transfer data to and from a control station, across a wifi network using python in both ends. I'm also wondering as to the best way to encode said data (csv?) to minimize encoding/decoding at both ends.